# What is the maximum size of a Litedb database and how to claim unused space?

Tags: c#, database, litedb

The limit size of all database and not only collections, and how claim unused space of delete data?

Update:
The question is about LITEDB and no SQLITE, some people don't even ready what is about.

Comment: Did you read the documents https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html?

Comment: i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @zaggler the question is about LITEDB and not SQLITE, LITEDB is a nosql db, here are the link for litedb, https://www.litedb.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Read the fine manual](https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/wiki/How-LiteDB-Works) - it says theoretically UInt.Max * page size (4096) = 16TB for version 4.x

Apparently, for 5.x, [PageSize is 8196](https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/blob/master/LiteDB/Utils/Constants.cs).

Comment: If you read the file manual that you linked to, the top of the page says "This documentation is valid only for v4.x version." v5 was released in late Jan 2020. The OP was asking the question in Nov 2021, so presumably they are using v5.

Comment: @Ants, tnx, updated the answer. Also, he might be using older version, he didn't stated which version he was using.